# Non-pod framework (GoogleTagManager) missing reference to library moved to pod

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

The use case is the following:

We developed an SDK, that uses, among other dependencies, GoogleAnalytics.
The SDK was shipped in old-fashioned way of adding our files + our other dependencies.
One of the dependencies is googleAnalytics lib, that the client's used later also for(by) GoogleTagManager (also non-pod import).

Now, we moved our SDK to be shipped as pod and all our dependencies (GoogleAnalytics libs i.e.) "moved" to the pod project with us, so the TagManger doesn't now include them (GoogleAnalytics looks missing in original project - "red" file).

Adding it also to the original project created a "duplicate files" linker error while the current state is raising linker error because tag manager doesn't have its GoogleAnalytics dependency.

What is the proper solution to this situation?
Why does it doesn't "know" the Google analytics lib from the pods target if the rest of the project do?